# Advanced WebGrid tutorial or solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am looking for some tutorial or solution that shows how can I make a Webgrid with few advanced functionalities at once: paging, sorting, `edit` and `delete` buttons for every row, checkboxes for every row, `edit` and `delete` buttons for rows that are checked and `select all` button.

I know I can make all those functionalities quite simply with jQuery and on click events. But I am looking for some clean solution that is made with good manners and using as much as it can from ASP.NET MVC technology...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After few days of searching and reading I have found few valuable tutorials and instructions that are worth reading if you will ever face similar problem:

- [Search, sort, paging, insert, update and delete with ASP.Net MVC and bootstrap modal popup PART-1](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1125/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1)
- [Search, sort, paging, insert, update and delete with ASP.Net MVC and bootstrap modal popup PART-2](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1126/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-2)
- [Extending the MVC WebGrid with HTML Helpers](http://www.emmielewis.com/extendingwebgrid/)
- [Insert, Update and Delete MVC WebGrid Data using JQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875859/Insert-Update-and-Delete-MVC-WebGrid-Data-using-JQ)
- [MVC 4 Razor: How to Select / Deselect All Checkboxes inside a Webgrid in ASP.NET Application using C#.NET](http://aspdotnet-kishore.blogspot.com/2014/12/mvc-4-razor-how-to-select-deselect-all.html)
- [How to delete multiple webgrid rows by using Checkboxes in asp.net MVC 4 Application](http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-delete-multiple-webgrid-rows-by-checkbox-in-mvc4.html)
- [Webgrid Paging, sorting and filtering in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/11/webgrid-paging-sorting-filtering-aspnet-mvc.html)

After reading them WebGrid functionalities are much more clear and simple and my knowledge of WebGrid is much bigger.